# convert an integer type array that contain values only 0 and 1 into string that should be simple sequence of array values in string form in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to convert integer type array that contain only 0 and 1 into string that should be simple sequence of array value not in any other form for example if array is

```
arr[] =  {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1}
```

than string should be

```
str = "0110100001100101"
```

than i want to divide it into two substrings like
`str1 = 01101000`(this is bit value of h as i know) and `str2= 01100101` (this is bit value of e) and want to convert these substrings into character `h` from `str1` and `e` from `str2`.

please help me .

Comment: show us the tried code

Comment: `want to convert these substrings into character h from str1 and e from str2.` can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: String s = "0110100001100101011011000110110001101111";  String str = "" ; for(int i =0 ; i<s.length()/8 ; i++) { str+=(char)(a);}  System.out.println(str) ; }} this code will print hello

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Arrays.toString()`

```
   Integer arr[] = {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1};
   String str= Arrays.toString(arr).replaceAll(",|\\[|\\]","").trim();
   System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: thanks a lot its really beneficial